# How do I run multiple CALL statements in DB2

Tags: c#, sql, db2, full-text-search

I'm trying to run multiple statements from DB2 (Windows 11.5) using remote SQL. So far I have:

```
BEGIN
CALL SYSPROC.SYSTS_CREATE('my_schema', 'my_index', 'my_schema.my_table (column1)', '', 'en_us', ?)
CALL SYSPROC.SYSTS_CREATE('my_schema', 'my_index', 'my_schema.my_table (column2)', '', 'en_us', ?)
END;
```

This gives me the following error:

`SQL Error [07004]: The number of variables in the EXECUTE statement, the number of variables in the OPEN statement, or the number of arguments in an OPEN statement for a parameterized cursor is not equal to the number of values required.. SQLCODE=-313, SQLSTATE=07004, DRIVER=4.26.14`

This is running from DBeaver but ultimately I want to run this as one command from C#, just trying to get the syntax right before I code it into the application. Note that each of the CALL lines work fine on their own.

Comment: Are you sure that the error originates from calling multiple statements? I.e. have you tried running one of them alone? I assume this is for i-series which I don't know, but the error usually means that you have an undefined host variable. Is the parameter marker (?) an out-parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SYSTS_CREATE procedure](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=routines-systs-create-procedure-create-text-search-index#sdx-synid_message) has an output parameter, and you must use the corresponding variable in a compound statement in your application.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE V_MSG VARCHAR (32672);
  CALL SYSPROC.SYSTS_CREATE('my_schema', 'my_index', 'my_schema.my_table (column1)', '', 'en_us'
    , V_MSG);
  CALL SYSPROC.SYSTS_CREATE('my_schema', 'my_index', 'my_schema.my_table (column2)', '', 'en_us'
    , V_MSG);
END
```

To run it in some tool like DBeaver you must change the statement delimiter from the default one (`;`) to some other like `@` and place it at the end of the statement.

The statement delimiter is changed in DBeaver in the Window -> Preferences -> Editors -> SQL Editor -> SQL Processing -> Delimiters -> Statement Delimiter field.

Comment: Much to my surprise, the following works in dbeaver 22.3.3 against db2 11.5.8 with statement delimiter ";"  `BEGIN
 call sysproc.admin_cmd('runstats on table sysibm.systables');
 call sysproc.admin_cmd('runstats on table sysibm.systables');
END;`

Comment: Awesome, this worked and worked from C# also. Thank you!!